# Any way to find out which NSF files are owned by the Domino Server

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Could someone please let me know whether there is any way how we could recognize a NSF file whether it belongs to the User or the Domino Server.
For example, Domino maintains its own NSF file like catalog.nsf, events.nsf, busytime.nsf, names.nsf etc. 
When I query the Domino Server to return all the NSF files, the server returns all the NSF files including its own NSF files like the above said NSF files. Now when my application comes across these domino related NSF files, it should skip extracting the data or it should not process the above said domino files and need to skip them.

My application is coded in JAVA.

If there is any way please let me know how I could get past this problem.

Thank you all!
Rajath

Answer (score 2):

You could build a list of the system databases based on the [System and application templates](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/6.5/help65_admin.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/f152b0b3a7dd915f85256d9b004b33d6?OpenDocument) list (here for 6.5 Domino server).

Answer (score 2):

There are specific Domino databases that are used exclusively by the server. A user with sufficient permissions can also access them. There is no programmatic means to distinguish "server controlled" datbases from others. You will need to keep a list of databases to "skip" in that case.

Looking at the list of [system templates for 8.5](http://www.pelm.it/help/help85_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/3c6d376a59c31827852574820001fa0b?OpenDocument), should provide you with a complete list that covers all releases of Domino. Now, bear in mind that this list specifies "ntf" file extension. You can substitute the names listed with an "nsf" file extension for your skip/ignore list.

If you haven't already done so, you can use "[DBDirectory](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS_JAVA.html)" class to traverse listed databases on a server, and filter out "ntf" files as well, if required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not organizing the databases into separate folders (Most system databases are on the root anyway) and then reading just those directories?